# MSTS and forecast function

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

My data is the hourly number of patients that enter the Emergency unit, meaning that I have 24 points of data per day like in the table below.

```
str(data)
'data.frame': 21840 obs. of 2 variables:
$ Date: POSIXct, format: "2017-05-01 00:00:00" "2017-05-01 01:00:00" ...
$ Freq: int 3 2 2 0 0 0 0 2 4 7 ...

data
Date Freq
1 2017-05-01 00:00:00 3
2 2017-05-01 01:00:00 2
3 2017-05-01 02:00:00 2
4 2017-05-01 03:00:00 0
5 2017-05-01 04:00:00 0
....
```

I'm trying to use the forecast package to predict the number of patients that enter the unit per hour with a month in advance.

I'm having some problems with the msts function and the forecast:

`msts_cons<-msts(data$Freq, seasonal.periods = c(24,168))` -> my first question is about the seasonal periods: are those correct? The first corresponds to a daily seasonality and the second to a weekly pattern. Is there a function to find other seasonality? Also, how can I indicate the correct start ( 2017-05-01 00:00:00) and end date ( 2019-31-31 23:00:00) if my data is hourly?

```
accuracy(fmcast,teste$Freq)
ME RMSE MAE MPE MAPE MASE ACF1
Training set 0.007965302 2.468848 1.840179 NaN Inf 0.6851999 0.0009135862
Test set 0.226633926 2.622561 1.940317 -Inf Inf 0.7224869 NA
```

When I run auto forecast on my data the MAPE is infinitive, this happens because some of my real values are 0, right?

Also in the forecast function the value h is the number of forecasts that I want, correct? So to predict a month of hourly entries I need `h=720`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so how do you define correct start date/hour and end date in msts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, those seasonal periods are correct for hourly data. But you are probably better off using the `fable` package which is much better at handling hourly data than the `forecast` package. The underlying data structure used in `fable` is a `tsibble`. See https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/tsibble/vignettes/intro-tsibble.html for an example of hourly data as a `tsibble`.
2. MAPE is a percentage error. When the denominator is zero you get `Inf`. This will occur in your case when there are zero patients for a specific hour.

Comment: To convert this data.frame to tsibble I use:
`dados = as_tsibble(data, index = Date)
> dados
# A tsibble: 23,400 x 4 [1h] <UTC>
   Date                Freq 
   <dttm>               <int>  
 1 2017-05-01 00:00:00  3
 2 2017-05-01 01:00:00  2
 3 2017-05-01 02:00:00  2`
But when I try the exemple in the book `fit <- dados %>% model(Freq ~TSLM())` the model is empty:
`> fit1
# A mable: 1 x 1
  TSLM(Demand ~ trend())
  <model>                 
1 <TSLM> `
I think the problem is in the missing key in "dados". In this case what would be the key?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please ask this as a different question, and provide a reproducible example.